# reset password by sending text using ionic and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i have an existing API and back end system, i am doing front end part (using ionic and angular create a mobile app) and now i want to achieve a function that reset password by sending a message on the phone to customer.

i have done reset password html page to allow user to input his/her mobile number, and then send it to API to get the id of the customer, but i don't know how to send a link associated to changing password to customer's phone.

```
<ion-view title="resetPassword">
<ion-header-bar>
    <h1 class="title">Reset your Password</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
    <form name="resetPwdData" novalidate>
        <p>
            Please enter your mobile number associated to this account !
        </p>
        <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Mobile Number</span>
      <input type="text" ng-model="resetPwdData.mobile" required>
    </label>

    </form>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something you must do from the API side.

You should call a service like `http://your-api/resetPassword/phoneNumber` from your app and the API should send a text message with a reset link (or a new password) directly to the phone.

You have multiple services to do that. You can check [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/sms) for example.

But you can't do it directly from the app.